# Error connecting to WCF service with Python suds

Tags: python, wcf, wsdl, suds

I am trying to connect to a WCF web service with Python suds. The link type is:

```
from suds import Client

url = "http://ipadress/Webservices/WCF/Service.svc?singleWsdl"
client = Client(url)
response = client.services.GetData(username, password)
```

The error I get comes from the urllib2 library, which is a dependency of suds:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

When I put the url in the browser I get the xml tree of the web service, therefore the link appears to be good. Is it a problem with suds not supporting these types of web services?

Comment: Have you tried to call the service url without the "?singleWsdl"?

Comment: It returns "Exception: No services defined" when i leave that part out